Assistance Needed with Master-Slave Configuration
I am reaching out regarding a critical bug in my application currently running in production. The setup consists of three servers, where one server (the master node) is connected to the database, and the other two servers (slave nodes) join the cluster to replicate data from the master node.
Recently, our system experienced downtime, during which the master node was down for a few minutes. After the master node came back online, instead of loading the latest data from the database, it joined the cluster and inadvertently copied stale data from the other nodes.
Here are the approaches I’ve tried so far to resolve this issue:

Set the cache rebalance mode to NONE on the master node and ASYNC on the slave nodes.
Attempted dynamic master assignment using:
ignite.services().deployClusterSingleton("DatabaseSyncService", new DatabaseSyncService(vertx, routerService, emiService));
Tried using backups, but this did not help since the service and database connectivity were lost when the master node went down.


I am sorry to present this, but why would anyone use an architecture that is inherently not a master slave architecture to create a master slave architecture? Master slave architectures suffer from a lack of redundancy of the master node! Ignite does not have that limitation. Ignite does not have a master node. If you have a 3 node cluster with 1 backup for all partitioned caches then  your cluster can not only survive a 1 node host failure, but it can remain fully operational under most circumstances! So rather than try to figure out your issue, please allow me to suggest that you simply switch to a normal 3 nodes Ignite cluster using at least 1 back up for each partitioned cache and now you will no longer have to worry about a "master" node going down because there is no "master" node! Hope that helps.

Please allow me to make it a bit more clear. By calling a node master, i meant that particular node was connected to the db and not an actual master. This is the node that went down and when it was up again, it loaded the stale data from the nodes already present in the cluster. The expected behaviour was that the node should have prioritized db instead of the existing nodes in the cluster. I am sorry if it sounded like an actual master slave configuration, I just have named it like that. Apologies for making it confusing. Please let me know if you can help.

Once again with a normal 3 node cluster with partitioned caches each node in the cluster participates in the interaction between Ignite and the backing database, not just one node. So once again your issue is that you are clearly not using Ignite in a clustered manner with distributed / partitioned caches. If you were to do that then if a host failed then the backup partitions would assume primary responsibility and continue to operate against the backing database and you would not have stale data! Hope that helps!

I understand now. What i did was removed the code where i was connecting db to just one node claiming it as a master. Now, every running node is connected to the db. I tested by making a cluster of 3 nodes and then stopping one container. Brought the container up after some time but it did not affect the data. Thank you for the clarification. This was my first stack overflow question I asked. Thankful to the community.
